# How to dynamically execute sql statement

Tags: sql

I want to execute an sql statement dynamically based on the column passed by user through jTextField.

```
 str=select "+jTextField.getText()+"  from table ;
```

This statement works fine of the column name does not have a space.
Example : suppose I have two columns = Priority and Request Type.

This above statement works perfect if I type priority but fails when I use request type

and
if I use the statement

```
   str=select ["+jTextField.getText()+"]  from table ;
```

then Request Type entry will work fine but Priority won't.

Any idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Not totally related to your question, but here's a tip: use 'PreparedStatement' for this case. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 1):

You may need to trim trailing/leading spaces from the field name, otherwise it should work fine:

```
str=select ["+jTextField.getText().trim()+"]  from table ;
```

Are you sure `Priority` is the right field name within that table?

Also be aware that you are vulnerable to SQL injection.  Suppose you put the following in `jTextField`:

```
  "null] FROM table; DROP TABLE table; --"
```

Then the result is

```
select [null] FROM table; DROP TABLE table; --]  from table ;
```